# Upgrade Paystation processor to 4.7 compatible

Tags: civicontribute, extension, payment-processor

After fixing some notices/warnings, I was quite able to configure and enable this processor on the contribution page.

When using this on a live page, I see an error after like

```
PHP Fatal error:  CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm::preProcess(): 
The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. 
Please ensure that the class definition &quot;nz_co_fuzion_paystation&quot; 
of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize()
gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition  
in /Users/jitendra/src/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php 
on line 323
```

I think as it doesn't actually follows the hierarchy CRM/Core/Payment/... this error is thrown.

Any thoughts?

Note:   `$this->paymentProcessor['object']` has a class named `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` though it contains the paystation object.

I cloned it from https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.paystation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've just done a civix install using the [developer guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/civix/) and managed to get it done using the latest code formats. Things I did was:

- Migrated the files to CRM/Core/Payment/...
- Created a mgd file which automatically inserts the payment processor into the db.
- Fix errors/warnings encountered during testing.

Sample upgrade [`commit - Link`](https://github.com/jitendrapurohit/nz.co.fuzion.paystation/commit/78492b39efc40332841570e96c77df907b7aea3a)

Comment: This handles the change for new 4.7 installs, but for sites upgrading from 4.6 to 4.7, it currently [seems it may be necessary to disable the extension before upgrade](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18081/is-upgrade-possible-for-payment-type-extension). Which means modifying contribute pages, etc :(