# Is upgrade possible for `payment` type Extension?

Tags: extension, payment-processor, developer, payment

I see extension of type 'payment' has been deprecated and hence not listed in the active modules we get from [`getActiveModuleFiles()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Extension/Mapper.php#L295) function. Due to this, any upgrade to this ext. is not possible since the upgrade link is not shown for them (as they are not active modules anymore)

Is there any way to upgrade such extentions - i.e to execute the following query in upgrade?

```
UPDATE civicrm_extension 
SET type = "module" 
WHERE full_name = "nz.co.fuzion.paystation
```

I haven't found anything other than the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Uninstall the extension form the site.
- Upgrade the site to 4.7.
- Make the extension compatible with the latest version - Eg - [Upgrade Paystation processor to 4.7 compatible](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17909/upgrade-paystation-processor-to-4-7-compatible) and Install the extension again.